# How can I get all the member usernames from a Twitter list

Tags: java, exception, twitter, twitter4j, endpoint

I am trying get all the member names from a list (group) in Twitter. I am using the following code -- but don't know why I am getting an error. For example, I am interested to get all the members from the following link -
https://twitter.com/journalismnews/lists/uk-national-journalists?lang=en

In this case, the owner name is journalismnews and slug (list name) is uk-national-journalists.

I am getting an error message as "Exception in thread "main" 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
message - Sorry, that page does not exist.
code - 34".

And the following is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;

public class TweetExtractAllUsersfromTwitterGroup {

public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException, TwitterException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb= new ConfigurationBuilder ();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXX")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("XXX")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXX");
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    String trgt="C:\\Twitter data\\usernames.csv";
    String ownerScreenName="journalismnews";
    String slug="uk_national_journalists"; //list name
    Set<String> members=new HashSet<String>();
    long cursor = -1;
    PagableResponseList<User> membes;
    do {    
        membes = twitter.getUserListMembers(ownerScreenName,slug,cursor);
        for (User mem : membes) {
            members.add(mem.getScreenName());
            System.out.println(mem.getScreenName());
        }
    } while ((cursor = membes.getNextCursor()) != 0);  
    try
    { 
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (trgt));

    for (String s:members)
    {
        bw.write(s);
        bw.write("\n");
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println ("--------------------------------------");
}
```

}